# Cumulative (running) sum of field Django and MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

```
class Tip(models.Model):
    prediction = models.ForeignKey(Prediction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pl = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=5, default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class Prediction(models.Model):
    fixture = models.ForeignKey(to=Fixture, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="predictions", null=True, blank=True)

class Fixture(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'm trying to get the cumulative sum of the field `pl` in the `Tip`-model, this grouped by the `date`-field in the model `Fixture`. I tried the following with the Django ORM:

```
Tip.objects.values("prediction__fixture__date__date").annotate(
    cum_pl=Window(Sum('pl'), order_by=F('prediction__fixture__date__date'))
).order_by("prediction__fixture__date__date")
```

But this query returns the cumulative sum per `Tip` instead of per date. How can I achieve this per date instead?

Answer (score 0):

Edit for the correct answer:

```py
Tip.objects.values(
    "prediction__fixture__date__date"
).annotate(
    cum_pl=Window(
        expression=Sum('pl'),
        order_by=ExtractDay('prediction__fixture__date__date').desc()
    )
).distinct("prediction__fixture__date__date")
```

I gives the query

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (
    ("transactions_fixture"."date" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') :: date
  ) ("transactions_fixture"."date" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') :: date,
  SUM("transactions_tip"."pl") OVER (
    ORDER BY
      EXTRACT(
        'day'
        FROM
          "transactions_fixture"."date" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
      ) DESC
  ) AS "cum_pl"
FROM
  "transactions_tip"
  INNER JOIN "transactions_prediction" ON (
    "transactions_tip"."prediction_id" = "transactions_prediction"."id"
  )
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "transactions_fixture" ON (
    "transactions_prediction"."fixture_id" = "transactions_fixture"."id"
  )
```

Just tested on a fiddle and worked fine, let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't produce a result with  ***distinct `date`***

Comment: This does indeed not work, this distincts *datetime*

Comment: @SanderBakker I edited the answer and tested it on a local env, let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: I cannot use distinct since my db engine is MySQL as specified in my question

Answer (score -2):

try this.

```py
Tip.objects.values(
    "prediction__fixture__date__date"
).annotate(
    cum_pl=Sum('pl', distinct=True)
).order_by("prediction__fixture__date__date")
```